# Use of .N and .SD in one call

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table as follows -:

```
data = data.table(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I would like to sum the numeric vector, only when the factor vector has more than one entry.
The problem I have will require the use of .SD. I understand that I could create a N field via

```
data[ , N := .N, by = V1]
```

and then sum via

```
data[N > 1, lapply(.SD,sum), by = V1, .SDcols = 2]
```

However, is there a one step call to do this?

Referencing .SD in the call doesn't return an answer -

```
data[, lapply(.SD[which(length(.SD)>1)],sum), by = V1, .SDcols = 2]
```

I would like to understand why this doesn't work. Neither does -:

```
data[, lapply(.SD[which(.N>1)],sum), by = V1, .SDcols = 2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about `data[, if (.N > 1) lapply(.SD, sum), by=V1]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data <- data.table(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5))
data[, if(.N > 1) lapply(.SD, sum) else NULL, by=V1]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  a  3
# 2:  b  7
```

Comment: Jeez, @Arun, I think our answers are identical character by character (nm, `else NULL` not necessary, wasn't thinking)

Comment: @user2006864 subsetting `.SD` will just return columns from `.SD` (and that's what you're trying to do in both examples), whereas what you need to do is return all of `.SD` if it has more than 1 _row_, and then sum the columns.  Notice how our solution does not subset `.SD` at all.